How to beautifully read different subtypes of yaml in golang
There is a multi-document yaml file which contains different documents (k8s CRD).
I don’t like the implementation below, it seems like I’m doing unnecessary steps for decoding and type conversions.
Help me write the GetAll function more beautiful/clearer.
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

const yamldata = `
kind: Kind1
spec1: AAA
---
kind: Kind2
spec2: BBB
`

type Meta struct {
    Kind string `json:"kind,omitempty" yaml:"kind,omitempty"`
}
type Kind1 struct {
    Meta  `json:",inline" yaml:",inline"`
    Spec1 string `json:"spec1,omitempty" yaml:"spec1,omitempty"`
}
type Kind2 struct {
    Meta  `json:",inline" yaml:",inline"`
    Spec2 string `json:"spec2,omitempty" yaml:"spec2,omitempty"`
}

func GetAll[T Kind1 | Kind2](yamldata string) (result []*T) {
    dec := yaml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(yamldata))
    for {
        var node yaml.Node
        err := dec.Decode(&node)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        var meta Meta
        node.Decode(&meta)

        var t T
        switch any(t).(type) {
        case Kind1:
            if meta.Kind == "Kind1" {
                var k any = &Kind1{}
                rzlt, ok := k.(*T)
                if ok {
                    node.Decode(rzlt)
                    result = append(result, rzlt)
                }
            }
        case Kind2:
            if meta.Kind == "Kind2" {
                var k any = &Kind2{}
                rzlt, ok := k.(*T)
                if ok {
                    node.Decode(k)
                    result = append(result, rzlt)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print(GetAll[Kind1](yamldata)[0])
    fmt.Print(GetAll[Kind2](yamldata)[0])
}



Define 'beautifully'.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Try to have Structs with Embedded Fields,
Instead of using type assertions and reflection, use structs with embedded fields to unmarshal YAML data more effectively.
Map Instead of Switch Statement
Instead of unmarshalling the YAML data multiple times, unmarshal it once and extract relevant data as needed.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "strings"
)

const yamldata = `
kind: Kind1
spec1: AAA
---
kind: Kind2
spec2: BBB
`

type Meta struct {
    Kind string `json:"kind,omitempty" yaml:"kind,omitempty"`
}

type Kind1 struct {
    Meta  `json:",inline" yaml:",inline"`
    Spec1 string `json:"spec1,omitempty" yaml:"spec1,omitempty"`
}

type Kind2 struct {
    Meta  `json:",inline" yaml:",inline"`
    Spec2 string `json:"spec2,omitempty" yaml:"spec2,omitempty"`
}

var kindMap = map[string]interface{}{
    "Kind1": &Kind1{},
    "Kind2": &Kind2{},
}

func GetAll(yamldata string) (result []interface{}) {
    dec := yaml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(yamldata))
    for {
        var node yaml.Node
        err := dec.Decode(&node)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        var meta Meta
        if err := node.Decode(&meta); err != nil {
            continue
        }

        if kind, ok := kindMap[meta.Kind]; ok {
            err := node.Decode(kind)
            if err == nil {
                result = append(result, kind)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    kind1List := GetAll(yamldata)
    if len(kind1List) > 0 {
        if kind1, ok := kind1List[0].(*Kind1); ok {
            fmt.Println(*kind1)
        }
    }

    kind2List := GetAll(yamldata)
    if len(kind2List) > 0 {
        if kind2, ok := kind2List[0].(*Kind2); ok {
            fmt.Println(*kind2)
        }
    }
}


Improved the function to the following form. Now I like her)))) But if there are even more beautiful options, don't hesitate to write!
func GetAll[T Kind1 | Kind2](yamldata string) (result []*T) {
    dec := yaml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(yamldata))
    for {
        var m any = new(T)
        err := dec.Decode(m)
        if err != nil {
            if err.Error() == "EOF" {
                break
            }
            continue
        }
        switch k := m.(type) {
        case *Kind1:
            if k.Kind == "Kind1" {
                result = append(result, m.(*T))
            }
        case *Kind2:
            if k.Kind == "Kind2" {
                result = append(result, m.(*T))
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

